# Pyautogui if Image is Not on Screen

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am trying to use Pyautogui to take a screenshot where another image is not found on screen. I have checked that the image is not there but my code is not executing.

Can anyone see the problem?

```
import pyautogui as py

if not py.locateOnScreen("sku2287.png", confidence=0.9, region=(245, 534, 123, 100)):
    py.screenshot('sku_absent.png', region=(45, 883, 423, 60))
```

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you get with `locateOnScreen`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the code witched wrote by [@Tanay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17675859/tanay) it is totally beautiful, but there is small mistakes which is if run the code :

```
import pyautogui as py
img = py.locateOnScreen("sku2287.png", confidence=0.9, region=(245, 534, 123, 100))
while True:
    if img == None:
        py.screenshot('sku_absent.png', region=(45, 883, 423, 60))
        break
```

if when starting the code and taking the value of img if img for the first time is not None. The value of img will not be updating will be still not None always, because img is not updating, so this code here

```
import pyautogui as py
while True:
    img = py.locateOnScreen("sku2287.png", confidence=0.9, region=(245, 534, 123, 100))
    if img == None:
        py.screenshot('sku_absent.png', region=(45, 883, 423, 60))
        break
```

is better cause the value of img will updating, and check if it is None or not

Answer (score 2):

Use while loop:

```
import pyautogui as py
img = py.locateOnScreen("sku2287.png", confidence=0.9, region=(245, 534, 123, 100))
while True:
    if img == None:
        py.screenshot('sku_absent.png', region=(45, 883, 423, 60))
        break
```

Comment: What's the point of looping? If it's not `None`, then the loop will repeat forever. But if it's `None`, then the loop will never repeat; the `if` statement will run exactly once and break the loop.

Comment: I think he needs to take screenshot if the image not exists and this code checks if image is none or not if it is then it takes screenshot and stops the loop.

Comment: I understand your intention; what's the point of the loop though? Either it'll loop infinitely, or not loop at all and exit on the first iteration; `img` is never being set within the loop, meaning the loop is pointless. Please explain why you think this needs to be in a loop and how your code is a solution, because it doesn't make sense at all to me.

Comment: @ Random Davis The code given in the question is working **if it is not present on the screen at the time of the execution of the program** _the motive of the loop is it will check till the image is not available_  if it is available than it will stop the program.

Comment: What do you mean that it will "check **until** the image is not available", when you only ever get `img` once, before the loop even starts? `if img == None` doesn't re-run ` py.locateOnScreen`, so it's either going to be `None` or `not None` by the time the loop starts. `img` never changes once the loop starts. Am I missing something here? Did you maybe make a mistake in your answer? Should the call to `locateOnScreen` be in the loop instead of before it?

Comment: See when i define the img variable and it **can not find** the image it will be None. And if the image is absent he needs to click a screenshot of the the area he has given. So my code checks if the image is None or not if it is not then it will take screenshot of particular area and stops the loop. You are actually correct the img never changes but my motive is to check **unitl the img is available**.

Comment: What would make it suddenly become "available" even though nothing is changing in the loop? What exactly do you mean by "available"? What's the point of looping when `img` can only be `None` or not `None` and it's set beforehand? Do you think that some other code is going to just magically change `img` during the loop?

Comment: You are correct nothing is changing in the loop but if i open the image in photo viewer and then run my code, image will not be available because the photo viewer had hidden under idle window.   **Plz understand my motive is realtime detection**

Comment: I don't follow your logic at all. None of what you're saying makes sense or explains the code you wrote, or why you put it in an unnecessary `while` loop.

Comment: I saw it here [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7Lkbi2KiSc)

Comment: I don't see it. That video was super obnoxious but I didn't see a `while` loop there anywhere, but I had to stop looking at it for my own sanity. What's the timestamp in that video where they have a while loop like the one you posted?