# Ubuntu 22.04: pyautogui.locateOnScreen is returning None. How to solve this?

Tags: python-3.x, whatsapp, pyautogui, ubuntu-22.04

My OS is `Ubuntu 22.04`, `Python 3.10.4`.
I am trying to create a code to automate Whatsapp send message.

Have installed latest version of `pyautogui`.

Following is the code I am running:

```
import pyautogui as pt
import paperclip as pc
# from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button
from time import sleep

# mouse = Controller()

class WhatsApp:
    def __init__(self, speed=5, click_speed=.3):
        self.speed = speed
        self.click_speed = click_speed
        self.message = ''
        self.last_message = ''

    def nav_green_dot(self):
        try:
            # position = pt.locateOnScreen('clip_pic.png', confidence = .7)
            # position = pt.locateOnScreen('clip_pic.png')
            # print(position)
            print(pt.locateOnScreen('clip_pic.png'))
            
            # pt.moveTo(position[0:2], duration = self.speed)
            # pt.moveRel(-100, 0, duration = self.speed)
        except Exception as e:
            print ('Exception (nav_green_dot): ', e)

wa_bot = WhatsApp(speed = .5, click_speed = .4)
sleep(5)
wa_bot.nav_green_dot()
```

At `print(pt.locateOnScreen('clip_pic.png'))` I am getting `None`.
Attached is the picture I am trying to capture.
I have already `opencv-python` installed as well.
I also have whatsapp web page opened in a chrome browser.
I tested in firefox as well.

The output error is not clear in what direction I should go.
What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that the size of your template ('clip_pic.png') must be exactly the same size on screen or you won't locateOnScreen will not work. Ideally the template and the region on your screen would be identical pixel by pixel.  You can also try setting the confidence parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding image on screen for only one time may be `None` you need to check **repeatedly** for it. And if it is found you can end the loop you are using to find it. You should use python's `multithreading` for it. here is an updated version of your code

```
import pyautogui as pt

import paperclip as pc

# from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button
from time import sleep
import threading
# mouse = Controller()

FOUND_IMAGE = False

def checkFunction():
    global FOUND_IMAGE
    while True:
        img = pt.locateOnScreen('img.png')
        if img != None:
            FOUND_IMAGE = True
            break


checkThread = threading.Thread(target=checkFunction) # creating therad

checkThread.start() # starting therad
class WhatsApp:
    def __init__(self, speed=5, click_speed=.3):
        self.speed = speed
        self.click_speed = click_speed
        self.message = ''
        self.last_message = ''

    def nav_green_dot(self):
        try:
            # position = pt.locateOnScreen('clip_pic.png', confidence = .7)
            # position = pt.locateOnScreen('clip_pic.png')
            # print(position)
            print(FOUND_IMAGE)
            
            # pt.moveTo(position[0:2], duration = self.speed)
            # pt.moveRel(-100, 0, duration = self.speed)
        except Exception as e:
            print ('Exception (nav_green_dot): ', e)

wa_bot = WhatsApp(speed = .5, click_speed = .4)
sleep(5)
wa_bot.nav_green_dot()
```

For any queries have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70346717/pyautogui-if-image-is-not-on-screen/70655622#70655622) or this [Post](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm#:%7E:text=The%20threading%20module%20provided%20with,force%20threads%20to%20run%20synchronously.)